# Bathroom light turns on 50% of the time

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, fans

I have two basic (non-dimmer) switches in my bathroom: 1 to control the light, one to control the fan, which are separate devices. The light is behaving very oddly, and it's been doing this since I purchased the house. First of all, the bulbs are new (LEDs, and there are two of them). Sometimes one bulb comes on, sometimes both. Sometimes only one bulb comes on, and then 5 minutes later the other one will kick on. Sometimes *neither* of them come on. In that situation, if you then turn the FAN on, once you turn it off, the light kicks on. This doesn't always happen the first try, but always less than 5. And it's always when you turn the fan OFF, not on.

I can't explain this phenomenon. I tried switching out the light switch yesterday with a new one, with no change. I can try replacing the fan switch as well, but I really don't understand how these two wire runs can be related. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: It is not `phenomenon` it is a loose wire

Comment: Type of light bulb might give a clue, but probably a loose wire.  Turn off the breaker and check for no power at the fan/lights.  Pull out the switch/s and the light socket and check wires for tightness on the screws.

Comment: If fluorescent bulbs, can have weird issues due to an old ballast (or starter, if really old fixture) and shutting the fan off might provide just enough of a voltage spike to kick it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a separate light fixture and fan the problem is likely in the wiring in the light fixture. Check that the connections for hot and neutral are tight at the J-box and any in the fixture.

Comment: At long last, this ended up being the problem. Nothing was obviously loose, but I finally rewired the connections in the j box and the problem went away. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Particularly because you sometimes have the problem with one bulb vs. both bulbs, I do **not** think this is a problem in the switch or in the junction box above/in the fan/light.

My hunch is that the problem is the bulbs themselves. Screw-in light bulbs in this setup are almost always **E26** base. This has been standard for over a century. While these are generally very reliable, there are a few possible problems that fit with your situation:

- Improperly sized and/or poorly built bulbs. Imported bulbs, especially LED bulbs, are often built poorly. I believe this is more of a problem now that it used to be as the bases of incandescent bulbs had to be built differently in order to maintain a vacuum or to keep an inert gas in (and regular air out). With LED bulbs this is not an issue, and shortcuts are often taken. Plus the base on an LED bulb does not have to withstand as much heat as an incandescent bulb, so the materials are often different (more plastic, less metal or ceramic).
- Improperly fitting base. This is particularly the contact in the center of the base. It often is a "tab" that is supposed to touch the bottom of the bulb as soon as you screw it in. Sometimes, particularly after many years of use, the tab does not push towards the bulb as much as it originally did, resulting in an intermittent connection - often improving as the fixture warms up, expanding the metal parts just enough to make a difference.

The long-term fix *might* be a new fan/light with integrated LED lighting. But a short-term fix is to try a different, preferably higher quality bulb.

Comment: "more plastic" as in _any_ plastic at all. There was never plastic in an incandescent bulb. There was no reason to spend the money for plastics that could take the heat of an incandescent bulb - it wouldn't buy any advantage to building the bulb or the bulb's lifespan.

Comment: And additional fix is _with the power **off**_, to gently bend the tab at the bottom of the socket upwards so that it makes better contact with the base of the bulb.

Answer (score 0):

Typical signs of loose wiring.

The Fan will induce some slight vibration that can cause the contact problems, specially in the no power slowdown cycle.

Since you replaced the switch, let's assume it is not that one.

Open the ceiling box and check for tight connections.

If you are new to this, make sure you turn off the circuit breaker.

Comment: I'd turn off the breaker even if I wasn't new to this!